# How do I fix the deformed text on the packet?

Tags: sculpting

[image]

I sculpted this packet in blender, but the artwork got deformed a little. How do I fix this? I've had this issue before when it comes to packaging creations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deformed you mesh after it was already textured, you can unwrap the distorted part again to fix it

[image]

Select the distorted area in the uv editor, invert the selection and pin the vertices with P

[image]

Then, unwrap again. It will fix most of the distortion

[image]

Comment: Omg thank you for this!